# How to contact a user?

Tags: support

Sorry if I am stupid but I don't find how to send a private message to a user. Isn't it possible ? I took a look at the user's profile as well as the faq.

Comment: Nope, not possible. The SE team seem to have strongly resisted this idea, though I think it could be useful at times.

Comment: If you let the person know you're trying to contact them via a judiciously placed comment (which you can later delete), you might get an email address from them. That's a hack (to be used sparingly), of course. :-)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think it could be useful too.

Comment: @cardinal Your moderators do not appreciate that hack, because we have to detect its occurrences and clean them up. Please use alternative mechanisms.

Comment: @whuber: (+1) I almost did not suggest it and felt a considerable degree of resistance to the idea myself. I intended it as a last-ditch sort of idea and also didn't fully realize it would generate more work on your parts (which I would like to find ways to further *minimize* anyway). Apologies. :)

Comment: (Please feel free to delete the offending comment, too, @whuber, if you feel it is best that it not remain publicly visible.)

Comment: In my case I wanted to point out one of my questions to a user because I think he possibly has a good advice about this question and I'm not sure he daily check new questions on stats.stackexchange. Hence I have followed @cardinal's suggestion with the help of a comment to a related question to which he replied: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26556/equivalent-mixed-models-yielding-different-results-in-sas

Comment: Stephane, I think *that* usage is fine, fairly commonly used already and potentially *beneficial* to the site as a whole since it presumably links related questions and content.

Comment: Yes, but I have noted that I do not always receive notifications to new comments on the questions where I have participated, hence I'm not sure he will receive a notification. Maybe this absence of notification is another question for meta.stats.stackexchange...

Comment: Since Aaron is the author of the answer, he will receive notification. The times you wouldn't receive notification as a comment participant is if (a) you are not the editor or author of the immediate post, (b) there is more than one non-author participant already *and* (c) the @-notification was not used to address you.

Comment: aaaahhhhhh now I understand the utility of @ ! Thanks !

Comment: As an example, note that, somewhat ironically, I did *not* receive notification of your most recent comment since whuber is another participant in this stream (but you *will* receive notification of this one!). ;-) A little complicated, isn't it! Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to contact other user?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/how-to-contact-other-user)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SE creates Q&A threads that are focused, undergo constant improvement, display evaluation by a qualified community, and permanently exist as references and search targets.  Ephemeral exchanges, highly localized discussions, and (undocumented, unwitnessed) offline dialog work against that effort and are therefore actively discouraged and--when they do occur--are quickly removed by the community.  Therefore efforts to engage in offline contact within the Q&A threads (including comments) are not supported and not appreciated when they do occur.

Nevertheless it's easy to contact people you meet here: check out their user profile.  If they want to be reached, they will include enough information to let you do that.  Another option is to use the chat facility.