# How to contact another user?

Tags: support, user-accounts, users

Someone posted a helpful answer to one of my questions. Now I want to contact that person. How can I do this? Can I send a direct email?

Comment: If they've ever used the Ten Fold chat room, you could ping them from there.

Comment: Oh -- the simple expedient of accepting an answer on either of your two open questions should give you enough reputation to comment anywhere.

Comment: @Glen_b of course I can make an answer and comment my own ones. But the problem is if I want to "add a comment" to another answer, then I get this message: "You must have 50 reputation to comment". Therefore, sometimes is necessary to write direct to an specific user.

Comment: @DarwinPC sorry but this is how this portal works. From our perspective nothing can be done with it. (You can write to the developers but I imagine they already got thousands of such e-mails.)

Comment: DarwinPC I believe you misunderstand. If you [*accept* an answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (see also [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)), you will get 2 rep. points. That will take you from below 50 to above 50. Your response seems to suggest that you don't know what it means to accept an answer; if that's the case, you'll need to read the site help in detail, because it sounds like you're missing an important aspect of how the site works. If you have missed that, you'll likely have missed other important things.

Comment: @Glen_b  I understand, thanks for your explanation :)  I accepted the answer and I didn't get the two points.

Comment: Darwin, you need to accept one of the answers on the main site, not on meta, if you want to have +2 rep.

Comment: @amoeba thanks for your suggestion, but I can't find the way to do that. I see only " This question may already have an answer here:  How to contact other user? 2 answers"  and this redirect me to another answer without options to accept it. Maybe, because yesterday I edited this question doing some specifications in the text.

Comment: Darwin, there appears to be some huge misunderstanding here. There are two different forums: the main site and the meta site. You have asked only one question on the meta site (this one), and it already has an accepted answer. But you have asked three questions on the main site (see here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/44724/darwin-pc) and none of them has an accepted answer. One of them is closed as off-topic, but two others contain several answers each. You should be able to accept any of these answers at any time. Of course you should accept an answer only if it answers your question.

Comment: @amoeba thanks very much for your clear explanation, I have got already two extra points necessary to add comments :)

Answer (score 11):

If they do not supply contact information in their profile, then you cannot contact them privately through this site.  SE does not work that way.  We respect our users' wishes to remain private.

If you think there is an emergency--for instance, if a user might inadvertently have posted sensitive information and you wish to warn them--then please just flag their post for moderator attention.  When you raise the flag you will be able to explain the reason.

Answer (score 5):

No (unless you happen to find him in chat). Only moderators can contact people via e-mail. For fuller explanation, see this: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) (meta-SO) and this: [How to contact a user?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/how-to-contact-a-user) (meta-Cross Validated).

P.S. I find the auto-suggest option while asking a question incredibly useful; think it is worth it to pay attention to the list of "Questions that may already have your answer" during typing - although it may take a few seconds for the script to catch up.

Comment: +1 Good link--thanks.